# ECLiPSe Prolog - IC library: Lists of integers as variables

Tags: prolog, clpfd

In the ic library, one can create a variable with a domain like so:

```
X #:: [1..10] % Variable X with domain the integers from  1 to 10.
```

It is also possible to create 2 variables with the same domain like so:

```
[X,Y] #:: [1..10]
```

How can I create 2 variables that have as a domain a list of integers?

More specifically, if I have a set of integers S, how can I make two variables that each has a subset (P1, P2) of S as to ensure that P1 and P2 have no common elements and that P1 + P2 = S?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand your question, you simply want to express that the two variables cannot take the same value. Rather than manipulating the domains, this is easier done with a constraint, e.g. `[X,Y]#::1..10, X#\=Y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lib(ic_sets)` in this way:

```
:- lib(ic).
:- lib(ic_sets).

test(X,Y):-
    LT = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],

    LA in_set_range []..LT,
    LB in_set_range []..LT,

    length(LT,N),

    #(LA /\ LB,0),
    #(LA \/ LB,N),

    insetdomain(LA,_,_,_),
    insetdomain(LB,_,_,_),

    X #:: LA,
    Y #:: LB.
```

`LT` is the list with the integer you want (it doesn't have to be a list of consecutive integers). `in_set_range` sets the domain of the two lists. Then `#(LA /\ LB,0)` constraints the interseption between the two sets to be empty (no common elements) and `#(LA \/ LB,N)` constraints the union of the two sets to have the length `N` of the starting list (i.e. number of element in the domain of `LA` + number of element in the domain of `LB` must be `N`). `insetdomain/4` instantiates the set and `X #:: LA` sets the domain of `X`.

```
?- test(X, Y).
X = X{1 .. 6}
Y = 7
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more)
X = X{[1 .. 5, 7]}
Y = 6
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 2, maybe more)
X = X{1 .. 5}
Y = Y{[6, 7]}
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 3, maybe more)
and so on...
```

Comment: This seems to be a convoluted way of expressing `[X,Y]#::1..7, X#\=Y`.

Comment: Indeed. But he inserts the word 'set' in the question so i decided to show it using set